# Sending or minting tokens to a user wallet using server side code

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, solidity

I have a deployed contract on `Goerli` and want to let users claim/mint tokens but I'm not sure how to make the user pay the gas fees since the transaction takes place on the server.

This is the working code on the server:

```
        const amountInEther = "15000000.01"

        const provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider("goerli", {
            etherscan: apiKey,
        })

        const signer = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);

        const DAI = new ethers.Contract(tokenContractAddress, ABI, signer)

       const txObj = await DAI.mintTo(secondWallet, ethers.utils.parseEther(amountInEther))

        return response.status(200).send({ txObj })
```

I'm thinking that this all needs to be on the server with api keys and privateKeys in env variables.

Any other suggestions are welcomed.

- Edit - I don't think I explained very well

I am building a game in which players accumulate tokens. At one point the player can claim the tokens. I was thinking of two options:

1. Mint the tokens and keep them in a wallet that distributes the tokens to the players by calling `transferTo` in the contract.
2. Let players mint their earnings directly by calling `mintTo` in the contract.

I want to keep the claim functionality on the server because I want to query the database using a user id from a token that will be sent to the backend. I don't know how to make sure that in the client the players will mint the correct ammount that they earned.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options would be:

- Backend resolves the amount of tokens
- Backend sings the message
- Client receives the amount and message
- Client sends claim transaction with the values passed
- Contract validates the signature and the values
- Contract mints tokens to the user

Additionally, I would add a nonce value to prevent multiple claims.

Solidity example:

```
contract ClaimWithSignature {

    address public _owner;
    mapping(address => uint8) _nonces;

    
    function claim (uint256 amount, uint8 nonce, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) public returns (bool) {

        address user = msg.sender;
        bytes memory hashStructRaw = abi.encode(
            user,
            amount,
            nonce
        );

        bytes32 hashStruct = keccak256(hashStructRaw);
        address signerRecovered = ecrecover(hashStruct, v, r, s);
        
        require(signerRecovered == _owner, "invalid signature");
        require(nonce > _nonces[user], "nonce too low");

        // ... mint tokens

        _nonces[user] = nonce;
        return true;
    }
}
```

and the signature generation would be

```js
import { $abiUtils } from '@dequanto/utils/$abiUtils';
import { $contract } from '@dequanto/utils/$contract';
import { $signRaw } from '@dequanto/utils/$signRaw';

export async function getTxData (userId) {

    let { user, amount, nonce } = loadUserData(userId);

    let encodedParams = $abiUtils.encode([
        'address',
        'uint256',
        'uint8',
    ], [
        user.address,
        amount,
        nonce
    ]);
    
    let hash = $contract.keccak256(encodedParams);
    
    let { v, r, s } = await $signRaw.signEC(hash, owner.key);
    

    return { user, amount, nonce, v, r, s };
}
```

*I've used an example from the test: [dequanto/ecrecover.spec.ts](https://github.com/0xweb-org/dequanto/blob/400b3abe9a90cad5005ce15e92f2bdcf37f90ab2/test/ecrecover.spec.ts)*

After the user has claimed the tokens, don't forget to update the nonce and amounts on your backend.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into it. The only problem is that the contract is already deployed. Or this would be a new contract?

Comment: If you want to validate the signature onchain, it could be a new contract, which then has permission to mint tokens.  Usually, the `mint` method validates the caller, and the caller would be the newly deployed contract.